# jQuery Not Recognizing Classes Added to Page Dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, jquery-click-event

I am working on a project, where I'd like to add many elements of the same class to a page, and make all of these classes accessible to a $('selector').click(); event handler.  What is happening though, is none of the dynamically added elements of the same class are responding to clicks.

To give you a better picture of what I mean, I made up a sample jsFiddle, which is very similar to the actual problem in my project:

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8LATf/3/

- One element of the class "added_element" is on the page already when it loads.  This element is clickable.
- A button is clicked, and it adds other elements of class "added_element" to the page dynamically using append.  None of these elements are clickable.

How can I make all of the elements of class "added_element" clickable? I'm guessing it has to do with the selector I use in the event handler, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[You need to delegate your handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_doesn.27t_an_event_work_on_a_new_element_I.27ve_created.3F). The easiest way is to delegate everything to the `document` using [`.on('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on) (this is how `.live()` is converted internally, as of jQuery 1.7):

```
$(document).on('click','.added_element',function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);    
});
```

[​http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8LATf/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8LATf/4/)

However, in your case, you can delegate to the `#container`, since all the added elements appear within that. Delegating to the closest possible DOM element is preferable for efficiency reasons, when it's possible.

```
$('#container').on('click','.added_element',function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);    
});
```

​
[​http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8LATf/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8LATf/5/)

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks for the help. I will remember that live() is deprecated.

Comment: I have the same problem, only the div I am trying to reach is not the immediate child of the #container. jQuery still doesn't seem to reach it because of this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use events delegation here, the correct way to bind event will be:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.added_element', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Here is a [corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8LATf/7/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, your answer was identical to the accepted answer, but the other guy posted first.

Answer (score -1):

When you attach the event handler to "added_element" the ones created dynamically via script isn't in the DOM. So there isn't a event handler tied to the newly created element.

To get around this, attach the event handler to the containing div instead, and make it look for "added_element".

jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yKJny/

Comment: Please make your answer more "self-contained".  Without clicking on your demo, I don't know if you're using `.live` or `.on`.  And whenever your link goes dead your answer is useless.

Comment: Since the OP used a jfiddle, it seems simpler just to link him back a working one. I'm not here to fish score, I just want to help the OP out. But, just for you, I will type my solution in the comment aswell!:)

Comment: It's not _"just for"_ me... it's for the benefit of anyone reading your answer when your link goes dead.  The purpose of this place goes beyond the needs of the OP.  Thank-you.